# the size of samples in each k-fold on GPU is different from the size of samples in each k-fold on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cross-validation, k-fold

I am running the same code training the same CNN model using the same dataset on GUP and CPU, and I am using k-fold cross validation in my code. The problem is that k-fold seems not working properly on GPU, because on CPU the number of samples that was used for training after the cross validation is about 700 samples in each fold. However, on GPU it is only 27 samples used for training in each fold.

I don't know what is the problem? could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code to debug the issue?

Comment: Actually, I am using this code: tf.random.set_seed(1234)  but I am not sure if I am using it in the right way or not ?!

Comment: It would be difficult to tell like that, I would need some minimum code to understand if the mistake is in the code or the possibility of a bug in any of the library.

Comment: I don't think there is a mistake in the code because I don't get this issue at all when I run the same code with the same training set on another laptop.

Comment: You can follow this link for use of K fold https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/